# mysql store procedure not inserting if all the columns are not inserted for a particular Table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

This is an example as I do not want to display my real table.I have 4 columns for a table `test` in mysql (phpmyadmin).

```
   CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `c1` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `c2` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `c3` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
    `c4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ;
```

and a stored procedure to insert only three columns which is not working.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `_c1` INT, IN `_c2` DATE, IN `_c3` VARCHAR(35))
NO SQL
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `test`(`c1`,`c2`,`c3`) values(_c1,_c2,_c3);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There is no error in creating the SP, or executing it. If I change the store procedure to insert all the four columns `c1`,`c2`,`c3` and `c4`, it works fine, for which all the parameters are given correctly as per the datatype I have specified. Note that I have specified the default value as `NULL` for the columns which would not be mandatory to be inserted every time.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Maybe `NO SQL` should be removed. Anyway **[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=2beabf42133a5b171e48f285e45a7f4b)**

Comment: The code you've posted here works correctly for me with an updated phpMyAdmin. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: sorry for the late response .The version is 4.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in mysql , try from command line to see if this is a phpmyadmin issue.

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `c1` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `c2` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `c3` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
    `c4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ;
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `_c1` INT, IN `_c2` DATE, IN `_c3` VARCHAR(35))
NO SQL
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `t`(`c1`,`c2`,`c3`) values(_c1,_c2,_c3);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

call testing(10,'2017-11-01','aaa');
select * from t;

+----+------------+------+------+
| c1 | c2         | c3   | c4   |
+----+------------+------+------+
| 10 | 2017-11-01 | aaa  | NULL |
+----+------------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes it is working from command line ,so maybe,its another bug in  phpmyadmin.Thanks you @P Salmon.